# MVC Javascript Button Value Incorrect

Tags: javascript

I am using MVC - in one of my views I have a button that I want to toggle the value on click.  Here's the button code in the view:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="button" value="Yes" class="btn btn-default" id="CanOrder" />
</div>
```

And this is my javascript for its click event:

```
<script>
    $('#CanOrder').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val('Yes')) {
            alert("button says Yes");
            $(this).val('No');
        }
        else {
            alert("button says No");
            $(this).val('Yes');
        }
    });
</script>
```

At the very beginning, this works...the button shows "Yes", and when I click on it I get the alert "button says Yes" and then it changes to "No".

But after that, what happens is whenever I click on it, it immediately changes the text on the button to "Yes", then I get the alert saying "button says Yes", and it changes back to "No".

If I try running the page without the alerts, I don't even see it ever change back to "Yes" - it acts like clicking it the first time works and then it only ever says "No" whenever I click on it after that.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you need to correct your equality check ` ...val() === "Yes".  Look up the use of jquery val(), looks like you are not using correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check the value of `CanOrder` you need to correct your if statement:

```
<script>
    $('#CanOrder').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
            alert("button says Yes");
            $(this).val('No');
        }
        else {
            alert("button says No");
            $(this).val('Yes');
        }
    });
</script>
```

You can learn more about the `val` method [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp).